# How can I create a model for water balance for a bunch of connected lakes?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, mathematical-modeling

So I am a bit stuck on how to start doing this question attached, since there are effectively $4$ lakes then water flow in can be represented by $F_o$ and diversions can be $D$ for variables but I am not sure on how to start build the model for the whole thing

$$\dfrac{dv}{dt} = \text{flow in} - \text{flow out}$$

So for example individually for lake $1$ (Lake Superior) I can write $\frac{dv}{dt} = D_1-F_{o1}$ and for the second lake (lake #$2$) I can write $\frac{dv}{dt} = F_{o1}-D_2-F_{o2}$ and similarly for the other $2$ lakes as well, so how can I create a model for water balance for the whole network?

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You have named your constants, but what are your variables?  And are the flow rates actually constant or do they depend on volume in the lakes?

Comment: @RobertTheTutor , variables are V and t, as far as I know the flow rate doesn't depend on the volume in the lakes, I think I am able to assume any reasonable initial volume of the lake

Comment: If the flow rates don't depend on volume then you basically have no problem. What you already wrote would basically be the whole story and every volume would vary linearly with time if at all.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor , ah ok so your saying I dont need to combine all the four equations to form a model for the whole network instead of just individual lakes?

Comment: I'm trying to confirm what is being asked for.  What does a solution look like?  Because $V = V_0 + (D_1-F_1)t$ seems a bit too simple.